# Python permission error when importing a png

Tags: python

**VsCode gives me this error:**

```
PS D:\leomu\Documents\Python projects\Bots> &
C:/Python/Python39/python.exe "d:/leomu/Documents/Python
projects/Bots/verify.py"
    File "d:\leomu\Documents\Python projects\Bots\verify.py", line 4, in <module>
    img = Image.open("D:\leomu\Documents\Python projects\Bots\FototsChat")   File
"C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2904, in
open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\leomu\\Documents\\Python
projects\\Bots\\FototsChat'
```

**when running this:**

```
import pytesseract, time
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("D:\leomu\Documents\Python projects\Bots\FototsChat")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string("img")
print(text)
```

Comment: 1. Both your images are the same. 2. Post your code along with the error & not as screenshots

Comment: Sorry its my first time posting on stack overflow can I edit my post?

Comment: It looks like `Image.open` has the path to a directory, not a png file

Comment: it's a permission problem... try running vscode as administrator (fast solution) but you'll have to give access to the folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load a file which is protected and cant be openened/changed by non admin users. To fix that, it depends what OS you are on

For windows users:
Open the terminal/your IDE as administrator and that should do the trick.

For linux/mac users:
Open run put `sudo` before your command to run the program.

Edit: i read the question better and realised the path to the image points to either a file without extension (like .png) or a folder (i suspect its a folder).

So if you are trying to open the file 'test.png' from within that folder, just do something like 'D:\leomu\Documents\Python projects\Bots\FototsChat\test.png'

Comment: Ran VScode as admin and still gave me the same error

Comment: What if you put the image in a new folder on your desktop, does it work then?